# AWS prediction api - database design

Tags: python, database, amazon-web-services, database-design, amazon-ec2

I have a forecasting api running on an EC2 instance that currently makes predictions when called. I plan to write ("schedule"?) a chron job that calls the API once per hour, and store the predictions as row in a database on AWS.

A row of data will have about 250 columns of numeric data. I plan to use this data to display to the user in raw form, but also, to do some computations across rows and columns (calculating errors, etc...). These rows must also be updated periodically. I need to access to these histories to calculate errors over time. For example, a row might look like, where **actual** represents reality and **"n-1", ... "n-240"** represents estimates made 1 hour before ... 240 hours before:

```
+------------+--------+-------+-------+------+---------+
| event time | actual | n - 1 | n - 2 | ...  | n - 240 |
+------------+--------+-------+-------+------+---------+
| 10/1/3 4pm |    223 |   200 |   190 | ...  |     180 |
| 10/1/3 5pm |     90 |   100 |   120 | ...  |     125 |
| 10/1/3 6pm |    165 |   169 |   180 | ...  |     182 |
+------------+--------+-------+-------+------+---------+
```

Important to also keep in mind is that this database table will be filled in diagonally, filling in columns as the data becomes available. So after one call, it might look like:

```
+------------+--------+-------+-------+------+---------+
| event time | actual | n - 1 | n - 2 | ...  | n - 240 |
+------------+--------+-------+-------+------+---------+
| 10/1/3 4pm |   null |   200 |   190 | ...  |     180 |
| 10/1/3 5pm |   null |  null |   120 | ...  |     100 |
| 10/1/3 6pm |   null |  null |  null | ...  |      67 |
+------------+--------+-------+-------+------+---------+
```

And the next call:

```
+------------+--------+-------+-------+------+---------+
| event time | actual | n - 1 | n - 2 | ...  | n - 240 |
+------------+--------+-------+-------+------+---------+
| 10/1/3 4pm |    205 |   200 |   190 | ...  |     180 |
| 10/1/3 5pm |   null |   130 |   120 | ...  |     100 |
| 10/1/3 6pm |   null |  null |   115 | ...  |      67 |
+------------+--------+-------+-------+------+---------+
```

Considering the data structure, style of updating, and computations needed, is this better suited for a no-sql or relational database? Every year, there will be 24 hours * 365 days = 8760 rows added.